# Cordova 10 unable to post ajax to http url

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, cordova, mobile

I'm trying to send json data to an http url without success (I tried to send same data to an other https with success).
I have this settings:
**config.xml**

```xml
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

**HTML Header**

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *;"> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *">

<script>
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: 'callback',
    crossDomain: true,
    async: true,
    data: {
      id: results.rows.item(i).id,
      bolla: results.rows.item(i).bolla,
      anno: results.rows.item(i).anno,
      magazzino: results.rows.item(i).magazzino,
      articolo: results.rows.item(i).articolo,
      quantita: results.rows.item(i).quantita,
      term: terminale
    },
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data)
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
      alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
      alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
      alert("status: " + xhr.status);
      alert("text status: " + textStatus);
      alert("error: " + err);
    }
  });
</script>
```

If I use json it returns `devicereadystate=0` and error if I use jsonp it returns `devicereadystate=4` and **error 404** (the url is correct if I paste to a browser it works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because with cordova-android 10.0.x, the webview is now acting as a https page and you can't load/send to non secure origins while using https.

From the cordova docs

> By default, the WebViewAssetLoader is enabled and allows apps to serve
> their content from a 'proper' origin. This will makes routing work
> easily for frameworks like Angular.
>
> With no additional configurations, the app content is served from
> https://localhost/. You can configure the hostname by setting the
> preference option hostname.

```
   <preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
```

> The scheme, https, is not configurable by nature.